# Export email addresses - Remove all email addresses that contain numbers

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, office365

I have the following powershell script:

```
    Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress | Export-Csv c:\userlist.csv -NoTypeInformation
Send-MailMessage -from noreply@domain.com -to username@domain.com -subject "Email Addresses" -Attachment "c:\userlist.csv" -SmtpServer relay-server
```

This gives me all the email addresses in exchange.  I have a bunch of email addresses that have numbers in the address like this:

123@domain.com

How do I massage the data so I only export email addresses that have letters?  I don't want any email address that have numbers in them to be exported to the userlist.csv file.

Answer (score 4):

Use the Where-Object cmdlet with -NotMatch

```
Get-Mailbox -ResultSize Unlimited | Where-Object { $_.PrimarySmtpAddress -NotMatch "\d" } | Select-Object PrimarySmtpAddress | Export-Csv c:\userlist.csv -NoTypeInformation
Send-MailMessage -from noreply@domain.com -to username@domain.com -subject "Email Addresses" -Attachment "c:\userlist.csv" -SmtpServer relay-server
```

Comment: I'm glad it works.  Also keep in mind it checks on both sides of the email address, so johndoe@123.com will also be filtered out.  

Please [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) my answer.

Comment: That's fine.  Thanks man!  Also, is there a way to store credentials in the script securely so I can run it from task scheduler and not be prompted to input my credentials?

Comment: Nevermind...I used the following to create a password file and then read in the password file: `$password = get-content C:\cred.txt | convertto-securestring
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist “user@domain.com”,$password

$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://ps.outlook.com/powershell/ -Credential $cred -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection
Import-PSSession $Session`

Answer (score 1):

On a side note, the code gives you just the primary address, if the user has more than one address you don't get them. You can use the EmailAddressess property to get all addreses (not just smtp).